# singleton class memory leakage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I set up a singleton following the instructions at [this tutorial](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/), but when I analyze it I see the following memory leaks:

[image]

How do I rectify this memory leakage in my singleton class?

Comment: +1 for using the static analyzer!

Comment: Let me make something clear: you can't copy someone else's tutorial onto your own ad-supported site and link to it from here. That's plagiarism and generally a violation of the original writer's copyright.  I've removed your promotional link and directed the question to the original tutorial. Do not do this again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that whoever that wrote that tutorial didn't write this right:

```
 [[self alloc] init];
```

Instead, it sould be:

```
_sharedMySingleton = [[MySingleton alloc]init];
```

I hope it helps

Comment: `self` in the context of a class method is the class that received the message, which in this case would be `MySingleton`. It's usually better to write this as `_sharedMySingleton = [[self alloc] init];` as Anders said. That way the code would work correctly for subclasses, should that ever be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You do not assign the allocation to a variable. Change it to this:

```
+(MySingleton*)sharedMySingleton
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
      if (!_sharedMySingleton)
           _sharedMySingleton = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedMySingleton;
}
```

**EDIT** my typing was too slow, others have already replied :)

Comment: You probably deserve the accepted answer though, with your full snippet!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you return _sharedMySingleton, it will still be nil. And hence allocated the next time, too. You should try setting it when the alloc is done.

Answer (score 0):

`[[self alloc] init];` - is not assigned to the object